# How to make this material with Voronoi texture in blender with the same color

Tags: texturing

[image]

How to make this material with Voronoi texture in blender with the same color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by combining two *Voronoi Texture* nodes, one set to *F1* and *Euclidean* from which I take the *Color* output. The other I set to *Distance to Edge* and use the only available output, *Distance*.

To make them both match each other, I plug an external *Value* node into their *Scale* inputs to change them at the same time. I also set them to *4D*, this way I can use another *Value* node to change the seed of the texture if I don't like the pattern.

The *Distance to Edge* I plug into a *Color Ramp* set to *Constant*, this way I can control how large the black areas between the colored pieces are.

Then I multiply the two with each other - the result are greyscale tiles with black gaps. This I plug in another *Color Ramp* node to give the greyscale values colors (starting with black to the left to keep the gaps black). For the texture coordinates I mix in a bit of a *Noise Texture* to make the edges of the Voronoi pattern more random by using a *Mix Color* node set to *Linear Light* and just a very small mix factor so that it's not too crazy.

I just made some similar colors to your reference, you can probably do better and by mixing with other noise etc. you could achieve not so homogenous colors - this is just to give you a basic idea.

This is the nodetree:

[image: node setup smooth]

And this is the result:

[image: smooth mosaic]

Optionally you can also use the pattern to drive the roughness and maybe a *Bump* node like I did in the next example, however your reference image looks like the surface is quite smooth so you can probably get away with my above setup.

[image: node tree with bump]

[image: bumpy mosaic]

Comment: Thank you very much for this help and your useful guide. Always be healthy